# Customers older than 6 months but not newer

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm requesting customers from the last 6 months in this way:

```
SELECT customer
FROM table
WHERE date_of_last_order>date_sub(NOW(),INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
GROUP BY customer
ORDER BY customer ASC
```

Now i also want a list of older orders than 6 months BUT it should NOT include customers of the last 6 months.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: What's the definition of customers of the last 6 months? Any customer, who placed an order in the last 6 months?

Answer (score 5):

You want to use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT customer
FROM table
GROUP BY customer
HAVING MAX(date_of_last_order) <= date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
ORDER BY customer ASC
```

Comment: Great solution Gordon! :-) Is it possible to add a `WHERE xyz!='0'`also in this CLAUSE? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since the table structure is not described, apparently those of `date_of_last_order` <= 6 months are what you want.

```
SELECT customer
FROM table
WHERE date_of_last_order <= date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
GROUP BY customer
ORDER BY customer ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

*Hmm...* what do you think, Gordon?  Wouldn't the `HAVING` clause only apply *"down-stream,"* to the rows selected so far?

Another possibility that comes to mind is `NOT IN` ...

```
...
WHERE date_of_last_order>date_sub(NOW(),INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
  AND customer NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT customer FROM table 
    WHERE date_of_last_order < date_sub(NOW(),INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
  )
...
```

... although "it sure is beginning to sound *expensive"* to me. I'd definitely want to apply the `EXPLAIN` verb to the various alternatives that I came up with, to find the one that MySQL decides is "cheapest."